# Map usage in Spring

Tags: java, spring, collections

```
import java.util.Map;

public class CoffeeShopMap {
    private Map<Integer,String> CoffeeShopWaiterMap;

    public void mapExample(){
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry : CoffeeShopWaiterMap) {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();

        }
    }

}

<bean id="coffeeBean3" class="com.cavalier.springcore.CoffeeShopMap">
    <property name="CoffeeShopWaitersMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="1" value="Michael" />
            <entry key="2" value="Peter" />
            <entry key="3" value="Steve"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

I am trying to implement dependency injection of Collections in Spring. The program gives error. I am not able to figure out the error.

Comment: What is the error? Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: Among other things, you aren't showing a setter anywhere (and you're violating the conventions that Spring uses to wire properties by not starting the name with a lowercase letter).

Comment: I've done [Set and ListFactoryBeans](https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog/blob/trunk/app/src/main/resources/spring-beans.xml#L238) frequently with little trouble, I'd check the Spring docs for their MapFactoryBean.

Comment: Thank you Chrylis, I corrected the naming convention.
Attached an executable code now

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.abc

import java.util.Map;

public class CoffeeShopMap {
    private Map<Integer, String> waiters;

    //Getter and Setter of Map waiters

    public Map<Integer, String> getWaiters() {
        return waiters;
    }

    public void setWaiters(Map<Integer, String> waiters) {
        this.waiters = waiters;
    }

    public void mapExample() {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> e : waiters.entrySet()) {
            Integer key = e.getKey();
            String value = e.getValue();
            System.out.println(key + " : " + value);

        }
    }
}

package com.abc
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class CoffeeShopTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("WaiterMap.xml");
        CoffeeShopMap shop = (CoffeeShopMap) context.getBean("w");
        shop.mapExample();
    }
}

//XML file named WaiterMap.xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="w" class="com.abc.CoffeeShopMap">
        <property name="waiters">
            <map>
                <entry key="1" value="Michael" />
                <entry key="2" value="Peter" />
                <entry key="3" value="Raj" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```